# Getting multiple fields, in event listener

Tags: php, forms, symfony4

For example if we got a POST_SUBMIT event listener,

```
$builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
  FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
  function (FormEvent $event)
  {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $form->getData();
    if($data) {
      $shippings = $form->getData()->getClientsShippings()->getValues();

      $form->getParent()->add('shipping', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => ClientsShippings::class,
        'placeholder' => 'Wybierz adres dostawy',
        'choices' => $shippings,
        'attr' => [
          'class' => 'chosen-select',
        ],
        'choice_label' => function ($shipping) {
          return "".$shipping->getJson()['clients_shippings']['name']." | ".$shipping->getJson()['clients_shippings']['ulica']." | ".$shipping->getJson()['clients_shippings']['miejscowosc']."";
        }
      ]);
    }
  });
```

and thats gives possibility to manage data but only form 'client' field. How i can add another fields to this eventlistener.

Why ?
Becouse i wanna create eventListener on delivery methods filed, and if i handle this event i wanna take CollectionType of products field and check how many products there is and do the math, how much delivery will coast.

So i need to get:

CollectionType field named 'order_products',
ChoiceType field names 'order_payment' -> get price table (is entity),

do the math,

and add new field TextType with value comes from maths.

Any idea how i can pass more than one field to EventListener or how to get this done ?

Comment: ok all what i need is just change to this: `$builder->addEventListener(` thx anyway

Comment: but ther problem is now that: `You cannot add children to a submitted form` any idea how to solve this all ?